# Angular 6 ошибка 500

Tags: angular

Когда я делаю `GET` запрос и получаю `500 ошибку` не могу взять эту ошибку и обработать его чтобы не получить такой ошибку в `console`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как его взять и обработать, чтобы  показать сообщения пользователя место этого?

П.с метку не мог создать

**index.component.html**

```
<tbody *ngFor="let item of category">
            <tr>
              <td>{{item.id}}</td>
              <td>{{item.translation[0].name}}</td>
              <td>{{item.status}}</td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
```

**index.component.ts**

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.paginDiss = 1;
    this.four = 4;
    this.pagination = [];
    this.fullPagination = [];
    this.restDataService.getData('category').subscribe((items) => {
      this.category = items['data'];
    });
  }
```

**service.ts**

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient, private router: Router) {
  }

  getData(dataUrl) {
    const url = `${environment.endpoint}${dataUrl}`;
    const header = new HttpHeaders()
    return this.http.get(url, {
      headers: header
    })
  }
```

Comment: Ошибка 500 - это ошибка на сервере, он может возникать если какие-то параметры не валидные вы отправили в запросе или при выполнении функции на сервере возникло необработанное исключение.

Comment: Да. Но хочу показать в модолном окне, чтобы если была ошибка пользователь об этом узнал

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Смотрите здесь https://angular.io/guide/http#error-handling

```
this.restDataService.getData('category').subscribe((items) => {
      this.category = items['data'];
    } ,
error => {

// здесь код для обработки ошибки
});
```